# How can I find out which distributions I can use in fitdistrplus in R

Tags: r

I have some data (x) and want to determine which distribution fits them best. 
I used:

```
descdist(x, discrete = FALSE, boot = 1000)
fit.norm<- fitdist(x, "norm")
plot(fit.norm)
fit.norm$aic
```

and did the same for weibull, gamma and lnorm. In the documentation I could not find a list of which other distributions (and the corresponding syntax) are possible. Does anyone know where I can find this information?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the FAQ you get if you type `??fitdistplus`

As documented, we provide initial values for the following distributions: `norm`, `lnorm`, `exp`, `pois`, `cauchy`, `gamma`, `logis`, `nbinom`, `geom`, `beta`, `weibull` from the stats package; `invgamma`, `llogis`, `invweibull`, `pareto1`, `pareto` from the actuar package.

Documentation also suggests you can use any distribution if you can specify it or find it in a pre-existing package.

Answer (score 1):

Add on to @Jacob's answer, here are two documentation pages I found really helpful where both the distribution names and the R syntax can be seen.

1. [Distributions in the `stats` package](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/Distributions.html)
2. [CRAN Task View: Probability Distributions](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Distributions.html)